# Cannot generate LaTeX from Isabelle/HOL under Windows7

Tags: windows-7, installation, latex, isabelle

I have spent too many hours trying to generate a .pdf document out of my Isabelle theory `Increments.thy`. The Isabelle build command gets stuck and apparently this is an installation thing on Windows. Frustratingly enough, friends have done this on their linux machines and they experience no problems at all. But I cannot find the right documentation to get it going on my Windows 7 laptop. Does anyone have the recipe?

I have a full LaTeX installation on my laptop, working like a breeze. I have installed CYGWIN, but it gave problems with access rights of files, that I couldn't solve (neither from the windows-end, nor from the cygwin-end). I tried various manuals, without much luck.

Answer (score 2):

With some hands-on help of the university of Innsbruck, I could finally generate a pdf from an Isabelle theory on my Windows-7 laptop. I'd like to share the result for the community at large. Here is what I did to make it work:

1. In Microsoft Explorer, I went to the directory that contains the Isabelle executables. This directory is called `Isabelle2016-1`.
   I found it by searching for Isabelle2016-1 in the file system. It is on `C:\Users\sjo\AppData\Roaming\local\bin\Isabelle2016-1`.
   I checked that it contains the file `Cygwin-Terminal.bat`.
2. I called the file `Cygwin-Terminal.bat` by double-clicking it.
   This opens a command-line interpreter (CLI), which is the GNU Bash interpreter.
3. In this CLI, I navigated to the directory that contains my Isabelle source code, `Increments.sty`, by issuing the command:

   ```
   $ cd /cygdrive/d/git/Publications/2017AFPproofs
   ```

   I used the command `ls -al` to verify that this directory contains my Isabelle source code file `Increments.thy`.
4. I generated a pdf-file `D:\git\Publications\2017AFPproofs\output\document\root.pdf` by calling Isabelle:

   ```
   $ isabelle build -v -D .
   ```

   I checked the result in Microsoft Explorer and displayed it with my pdf-viewer.

That worked.

Comment: Are you by chance using libisabelle? If so, what exactly have you tried to build your document?

Comment: I got the impression you were using libisabelle because your installation is in `%APPDATA%`. But on second thought this might be also an artifact of how your setup in Innsbruck works.

Comment: No, I'm not using libisabelle (as far as I know). I'm mostly running into the things newbies always run into. Once you're up and running, such problems tend to disappear. In the meantime it keeps many newbies outside, who cannot take the hurdle for lack of the right friends. Btw, I'm not working from Innsbruck, but from Holland. I just got their help, because they use Isabelle a lot.

Comment: For steps 3 and 4, this works because you have the ROOT file setup right, which is described in chapters 2 and 3 of http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/system.pdf

Comment: @user1933930 Okay then, but what exactly did you do to run `isabelle build` that got stuck, if not from Cygwin? It could be a bug in Isabelle, but it's unclear to me what the problem might be. Any additional information could be good for confirming the problem.